# VB.NET - instantiate a class using a string variable for the Class namespace?

Tags: vb.net, instantiation

Here is the concept:

1. Load data from XML file where an element represents the name of a Theme class (i.e. "aTheme")
2. Instantiate the class based on the string ("aTheme") ... Dim myObject = New aTheme

Trying to replace a structure like this:

```
Select Case loadedTheme
   Case "aTheme"
      Dim myObject as New aTheme
   Case "bTheme"
      Dim myObject as New bTheme
   Case "cTheme"
      Dim myObject as New cTheme
End Select
```

with something more elegant and flexible rather than a hardcoded case.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered Reflection?

Comment: As suggested, you would need to use Reflection to create an instance of a type by name. You should also make sure that all the types you want to instantiate either inherit a common base class or implement a common interface where all the members you want to use are declared. That way, you can cast the object created as that common type and access those members directly. If you don't, you will only have an `Object` instance and you'd have to use Reflection to access members too.

Comment: You can use `Activator.CreateInstance` method and it's overloads, check here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Can you show how this class is used? There are better, more dynamic approaches are possible, but correct one depends on the usage. Are you in control of the xml file content? Do you want that new classes can be added without changing any consumption code, but just by adding new class?

Comment: I had thought about using Reflection but it has some pretty significant performance concerns ... fortunately this is one time only on app start so I might be able to get away with that, however users like snappy app startups.

Comment: Yes, I control of the XML file that will have the loadedTheme value.  I should clarify that "MyObject" is not representative of my construct.  I'm not in control of the class (MyObject) nor the Theme ... it's actually this StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = New GreenTheme where both are Telerik and each "theme" is a Telerik class.